# How to add execute custom function in switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, addclass

I am trying to execute a switch statement based on the argument passed to the function below and I tried to execute different functions based on the argument passed. But I am getting  Uncaught ReferenceError: of another function in the beginning of the .js file when i tried a function in the third case as shown below.

```
function getjobCon(reqType){

       var identifier= $( "#single" ).val();

          switch (reqType) { 
                            case 'job': 
                                alert('you clicked job');
                                break;
                            case 'title': 
                                alert('you clicked title');
                                break;
                            case 'designation': function(identifier){
                                 $(this).addClass('slate');

                            }                                   
                                break;      

                            }
                    }
```

can someone tell me how I can do this ?. I tried alot but couldn't get it corrected.

JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ck221xxk/

Note - I am executing this function when different buttons are clicked. And I am changing the class of the button in the third case where I am trying to execute another function.

Comment: A fiddle or pen might help

Comment: I will add a fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: Added. If I name the function or if I declare another function, it works. But I don't want to name it.

Comment: why anyone would want to wrap a line(s) of code in an anonymous function, just to do it, is beyond me. Just put the code within the case statement. Unless you just want to make it difficult to read.

Comment: I will be making an ajax call in the function with the variable. Can start the ajax call in place of the function ?

Comment: Of course you can, but you might have to change the example you're probably using...

Comment: i don't mean to give you a hard time, but if you ever get a minute, check out this, it is a very good **read**. it _should_ help with some of your questions. http://javascript.crockford.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. The function you have specified is not being called (the switch statement is not calling it). A switch statement is just a construct within JavaScript, and a `:` in a switch statement, does not mean `=` as it does in a *object literal*. (Didn't notice this myself first, so thanks @WhiteHat).
2. `this` changes value from function to function. `this` in your *outer function* may mean "the current HTML-node" but inside the anonymous function, it will most likely refer to `window` unless something different is defined.
3. Defining in-line functions like that is a syntax error.

You *can* of course have functions in-line; but you need to wrap it in brackets `()`, and call it with `()` [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or similar.

I will use [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) since the first argument specified in [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is the `this`-argument, meaning that i can keep `this` "the same" in both contexts.

```
function getjobCon(reqType) {

  var identifier= $( "#single" ).val();

  switch (reqType) { 
      case 'job': 
          alert('you clicked job');
          break;
      case 'title': 
          alert('you clicked title');
          break;
      case 'designation': 
          (function(identifier){

           $(this).addClass('slate');

          }).call(this, identifier);                                   
          break;      
      }
   }
}
```

However, unless you *badly* need a new namespace, I don't see any reason to do this, any of the other answers would probably suffice.

Comment: Defining an uncalled anonymous function like that within a switch statement is kind of pointless.

Comment: Fixing, I don't think OP included a full example.

Comment: Nope, it is not. I thought it was a return statement in front of it. I'm tired.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. I know if I name the function or write it separately works. But wanted to know if I can declare without doing it. I will take one of the idea. Sorry if I was not clear. Thanks once again for your time.

Comment: Thank you a bunh @whitehat. Yeah, I tent to try to implement stuff in interesting ways. :) I'm not sure what op is asking exactly. ^^

Comment: My solution doesn't "name" (or assign) the function, it just calls it "in-line"

Comment: I noticed that and chosen your answer. Thanks all. Let me try this answer.

Answer (score 2):

just remove the function statement, no need for it, or simply call your own as shown here...

```
function getjobCon(reqType){
   var identifier= $( "#single" ).val();

      switch (reqType) { 
                        case 'job': 
                            alert('you clicked job');
                            break;
                        case 'title': 
                            alert('you clicked title');
                            break;
                        case 'designation': 
                            customFunc(identifier);
                            break;      
                        }
                }

function customFunc(identifier) {
  // put code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't just want to add class. I will be adding more functionalities in the function. So the custom function is needed.

Comment: You could simply execute another function

Comment: Then see my answer @BigB

Comment: The revision that @WhiteHat added should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call your next function inside of that case

```js
function getjobCon(reqType) {
  var identifier = $("#single").val();

  switch (reqType) {
    case 'job':
      alert('you clicked job');
      break;
    case 'title':
      alert('you clicked title');
      break;
    case 'designation':
      doStuff(identifier);
      break;
  }
};

function doStuff(identifier){
  // execute other code here
};
```